# I want to add two y axis values in a bokeh line plot

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

whats wrong with this line of code..please help

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

output_file ('newfile.html')

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ASyed\OneDrive -      NKT\PythonProject\bokehPractise\newfile\19AJ100429-GC3-FR-003-A1-KP240.000-KP248.831-SL-AT.xlsx', \
sheet_name= 'Listing')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = [x.replace("\n", " ") for x in df.columns.to_list()]

SOURCE = ColumnDataSource(data = df)
p = figure (plot_width = 800, plot_height = 600)


p.line(x= 'KP [km]', y =[['DOL [m]'], ['DOC [m]']], source = SOURCE )
p.title.text = 'DOL Visualization'
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Kilometer Point'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'DOC'

show(p)
```

I am using pandas and bokeh. i want a plot with two y axis lines derived from two different columns. Above code gives following error and a plank bokeh plot in html.

```
Expected y to reference fields in the supplied data source.

When a 'source' argument is passed to a glyph method, values that are sequences
(like lists or arrays) must come from references to data columns in the source.

For instance, as an example:

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=a_list, y=an_array))

    p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source, ...) # pass column names and a source

Alternatively, *all* data sequences may be provided as literals as long as a
source is *not* provided:

    p.circle(x=a_list, y=an_array, ...)  # pass actual sequences and no source
```

Comment: It is hard to solve the problem, if we can not reproduce your example. We don't have your excel file. Please provide your DataFrame and your error message (also from the browser console).

Comment: I suspect error is in this code line "p.line(x= 'KP [km]', y =[['DOL [m]'], ['DOC [m]']], source = SOURCE )" . Here KP [km], DOL [m] and DOC [m] are column names from excel. I want to plot two column values on y axis

Comment: console error - bokeh-2.4.2.min.js:183 
        
       [bokeh] attempted to retrieve property array for nonexistent field 'KP [km]'

Comment: The error in the console means, that the `ColumnDataSource` object can not find an entry named `'KP [km]'`. Please check the column names of your DataFrame using `print(df.columns)`. Please also add `print(df.head())` to your question. So it is possible to see the structure of your DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `source` as an input to your figure, you are only allowed to add strings as a pointer to the data.

In your case use

```
p.line(x= 'KP [km]', y ='DOL [m]', source = SOURCE )
```

instead of

```
p.line(x= 'KP [km]', y =[['DOL [m]'], ['DOC [m]']], source = SOURCE )
```

If you want to add multiple lines to one figure, call the `p.line()` once for each line.

### Minimal Example

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.line(x='index', y='a', source=source)
p.line(x='index', y='b', source=source, color='red')

show(p)
```

[image: multiple line plot]

### See also

Check out the [multiline example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps/first_steps_1.html#combining-multiple-graphs) on the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks!!! adding separate p.line() for each line helped...thanks you for taking time